# Grouping the elements of arrays in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, ipython

I have 3 different arrays in python like

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [6,7,8 ]
c = [20,21,22]
```

And I want to create an array which will group the elements from the 3 arrays like

```
array = [[1,6,20],[2,7,21],[3,8,22]]
```

What is the easiest way to do it? Any help? Thank you in advance

Comment: [zip(a, b, c)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Why `[8 9 22]`? Where did 3 and 4 go?

Comment: Can you please clarify your expected result ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use zip to create desire result, But zip will make list of tuples, So using list comprehension on top of it.

```
[list(x) for x in zip(a,b,c)]
```

Comment: What about the mysteriously missing 3 and 4 out of the first list?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with zip and map in one line of code.

```
map(list, zip(a,b,c))
```